# Inconsistent behavior of Matlab regular expression with tokens

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a set of strings (several thousand in all) I need to parse that look like these:

```
'22-213-1-0,0'
'4-23-1-1,0'
'85-572A-1-1,0'
'3-13-1-1,0'
'6-58A-1-1,0'
```

I want the first number (not digit!), second number and letter (if it exists) returned separately:

```
'22' '213' ''
'4'  '23'  ''
'85' '572' 'A'
'3'  '13'  ''
'6'  '58'  'A'
```

I used a regular expression to do this:

```
input = {'22-213-1-0,0' '4-23-1-1,0' '85-572A-1-1,0' '3-13-1-1,0' '6-58A-1-1,0'}'

test='(\d*)+[-]+(\d*)+(\w)+[-]\w*';

for i=1:length(input)

    parsedstring=regexp(input(i),test,'tokens');
    output(i,1)=cellfun(@str2num,parsedstring{1}{1}(1));
    output(i,2)=cellfun(@str2num,parsedstring{1}{1}(2));
    letter(i)=parsedstring{1}{1}(3);
end
```

But the results seem inconsistent:
output =

```
22    21
 4     2
85   572
 3     1
 6    58
```

letter =

```
'3'    '3'    'A'    '3'    'A'
```

Why is the regexp sometimes returning only the first digit of that second number? I thought it might happen when the first number is only 1 digit long, but the last string proves that sometimes it parses a single digit correctly. 
What am I missing?

Comment: All you need to do is change `test` to `'(\d*)+[-]+(\d*)+(\w?)+[-]\w*'`; but `test='(\d*)-(\d*)(\w?)-.*';` would be cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to specify [*zero* or one](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) word character with `\w?` rather than just `\w`.  As I said in my comment, this means you could update `test` to,

```
test='(\d*)-(\d*)(\w?)-.*';
```

Answer (score 1):

my 2 cents (if your data is always in the format you provided):

```
(\d+)-(\d+)([a-zA-Z])?.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an **anchor**, first of all, *i.e.* `^`. Also, here's a simpler expression:

```
^(\d+)-(\d+)(\w?)-
```

The `?` is another quantifier (in addition to `+` and `*`) that means "zero or one."

I'm trying to find an explanation for the behavior of your regex as well, but it's hard to tell. It probably has something to do with things like `(\d*)+` where you're multiply quantifying atoms, and certainly to do with some kind of backtracking. I'll edit my answer if I figure it out.